# Returning plain text Strings and raw json Strings from Spring controller with correct content-type

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, content-type

I have Spring(version 3.2.9) controller that return Strings. Some methods return plain text and some return JSON.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/json", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public String json() {
    return "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/text", produces = "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public String text() {
    return "foobar";
}
```

I can configure StringHttpMessageConverter to set correct content type for one of those like this

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

OR

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

I also tried to give array containing both (application/json and plain/text) types as parameter for supportedMediaTypes but Content-Type was set to type that was first on the array like this

```
<property name="supportedMediaTypes">
   <array>
      <value>application/json; charset=UTF-8</value>
      <value>text/plain; charset=UTF-8</value>
   </array>
</property>
```

I know that I can write directly to HttpResponses outputstream but I would like to use @ResponseBody instead.

How can I configure Spring so that it returns strings but sets Content-Type to what I have specified in "produces" parameter?

Comment: The value of `Content-Type` header depends on the value of `Accept` header of the request. _I also tried to give array ..._ - how?